# Numbering sidebar elements based on start/finish variables

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a numbering system that compliments another javascript library for numbering documentation.

I know this can be done in CSS but because this gets rendered and outputted as static HTML afterwards this is the least client side rendering opposed to some CSS bugs I was fighting.

I'm particularly interested in the javascript section for review, as the HTML and CSS are here for demo.

I don't like this section:

```js
const sidebarListItemsH1 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH2 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH3 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH4 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH5 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH6 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
```

But I don't know of a better way of doing it.

I tried to loop over the `li` element, and then if it was an `ul` add a different number. But everything I had tried wasn't working or returning empty values.

```js
// dummy settings
const startLevel = 1; // top most heading level
const finishLevel = 6; // bottom most heading level
const separator = "."; // what separates the numbers
let dummyNumbers = "1.0.0.0.0.0"; // starting numbers

// manipulation
dummyNumbers = dummyNumbers.split(separator);
dummyNumbers = dummyNumbers
  .concat(new Array(6).fill(0))
  .slice(0, 6)
  .map((x) => +x);

// -- get the navigation sidebar items
const sidebarList = document.querySelectorAll("div.sidebar-nav ul");

// -- for all the <ul> items
sidebarList.forEach((listItem) => {
  // set the previous item
  let previousElement = listItem.previousElementSibling;

  // exit if null
  if (!previousElement) return;

  // if <ul> and previous was <li>
  if (
    listItem.parentNode.nodeName.toLocaleUpperCase() == "UL" &&
    previousElement.nodeName.toLocaleUpperCase() == "LI"
  ) {
    // -- move it into the previous
    previousElement.appendChild(listItem);
  }
});


// -- get the elements
const sidebarListItemsH1 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH2 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH3 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH4 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH5 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');
const sidebarListItemsH6 = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li');

// -- add the attributes
sidebarListItemsH1.forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute("heading", "1");
});
sidebarListItemsH2.forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute("heading", "2");
});
sidebarListItemsH3.forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute("heading", "3");
});
sidebarListItemsH4.forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute("heading", "4");
});
sidebarListItemsH5.forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute("heading", "5");
});
sidebarListItemsH6.forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute("heading", "6");
});

const sidebarListItems = document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar-nav li');

const headingStartingNumbers = [
  0, // null
  dummyNumbers[0] - 1, // h1
  dummyNumbers[1] - 1, // h2
  dummyNumbers[2] - 1, // h3
  dummyNumbers[3] - 1, // h4
  dummyNumbers[4] - 1, // h5
  dummyNumbers[5] - 1, // h6
];

// sidebarListItems.forEach( (item) => {
for (var item in sidebarListItems) {

  let numberText = '';
  let heading = sidebarListItems[item];

  // -- regex to match on
  const headingRegex = new RegExp(
    `^([${startLevel}-${finishLevel}])$`
  );

  // element does not match a heading regex
  if (!heading ||
    !heading.tagName ||
    !heading.getAttribute('heading').match(headingRegex)
  ) continue;

  // -- set the number value from the added attribute
  const headingNumber = (
    parseInt(heading.getAttribute('heading'), 10) || 0
  );

  // return the heading level number
  headingStartingNumbers[headingNumber]++;

  // loop from 1-6 (H1 to H6)
  for (var levelNumber = 1; levelNumber <= 6; levelNumber++) {

    // -- if loop index less than attribute heading number
    if (levelNumber <= headingNumber) {

      // -- add the number to the variable
      numberText += headingStartingNumbers[levelNumber] + separator

      // -- exit out if out of range
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  // add to the text
  heading.querySelector('a').innerHTML = numberText + ' ' + heading.querySelector('a').innerHTML
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
}

pre {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}

aside {
  left: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Title 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Title 2</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Title 3</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Title 4</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Title 5</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Title 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <li><a>Title 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Title 2-1</a></li>
        <li><a>Title 2-2</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Title 3-1</a></li>
          <li><a>Title 3-2</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Title 4-1</a></li>
            <li><a>Title 4-2</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Title 5-1</a></li>
              <li><a>Title 5-2</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Title 6-1</a></li>
                <li><a>Title 6-2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

**Expected outputs:**

```html
Expected output:
// seqential numbers
1. Title 1
1.0. Title 2
1.0.0. Title 3
1.0.0.0. Title 4
1.0.0.0.0. Title 5
1.0.0.0.0.0. Title 6

// nested numbering
2. Title 1
2.0. Title 2-1
2.1. Title 2-2
2.1.0. Title 3-1
2.1.1. Title 3-2
2.1.1.0. Title 4-1
2.1.1.1. Title 4-2
2.1.1.1.0. Title 5-1
2.1.1.1.1. Title 5-2
2.1.1.1.1.0. Title 6-1
2.1.1.1.1.1. Title 6-2

// altering the dummyNumbers and separator
// dummyNumbers = 30.1.5.8.9.3
// separator = '-'
30- Title 1
30-1- Title 2
30-1-5- Title 3
30-1-5-8- Title 4-1
30-1-5-9- Title 4-2
30-1-5-9-0- Title 5
30-1-5-9-0-0- Title 6

// altering start and finish numbers
// startLevel = 2
// finishLevel = 4
Title 1
1.0. Title 2
1.0.0. Title 3-2
1.0.1. Title 3-2
1.0.1.0. Title 4
Title 5
Title 6-1
Title 6-2
```

Comment: The expected output is a bit strange. Should the count of the nested elements not reset when moving on to a next `<ul>`? At the moment you have `1.0` and `2.1`. Should `2.1` not start at `2.0`? Or should `1.0` not start at `1.1`? What if there is both an `1.0` and `1.1` present? Should the fist element under `2` then be `2.2`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r - error on my part of labelling output. It should all start at `.0` and then increment from that. I'll update it now